# Importing multiple tables within a single file

Tags: import

Suppose I have a file with multiple tables, each separated by a line beak, like this:

```
banana yellow
apple red
grape purple

fire red
water blue
sky blue

parrot green
whale blue
cat yellow
```

I need to create three lists of ordered pairs out of this single file. If I had just a single table, I'd simply use `data = Import["file.dat", "Table"]`, but in this case I don't know how to tell *Mathematica* to split into three tables and that I need a `data1`, a `data2` and a `data3`.

Answer (score 8):

This is one way:

```
str = "banana yellow
 apple red
 grape purple

 fire red
 water blue
 sky blue

 parrot green
 whale blue
 cat yellow";

DeleteCases[SplitBy[ImportString[str, "Table"], # === {} &], {{}}]

(* ==>

{{{"banana", "yellow"}, {"apple", "red"}, {"grape", "purple"}}, 
 {{"fire", "red"}, {"water", "blue"}, {"sky", "blue"}}, 
 {{"parrot", "green"}, {"whale", "blue"}, {"cat", "yellow"}}}

*)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Szabolcs'solution better, but here is my alternative:

```
str = "banana yellow
apple red
grape purple

fire red
water blue
sky blue

parrot green
whale blue
cat yellow";

ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ StringSplit[ImportString[str, "String"], "\n\n"]

(* {{{"banana", "yellow"}, {"apple", "red"}, {"grape", "purple"}}, 
    {{"fire", "red"}, {"water", "blue"}, {"sky", "blue"}}, 
    {{"parrot", "green"}, {"whale", "blue"}, {"cat", "yellow"}}} *)
```

Note that the rightmost `ImportString` stands for the `Import` that you would normally do to import a file (the `ImportString` is used here for demonstration purposes,  so that no external file is needed). The leftmost `ImportString` should be exactly as it is.